# Why is the html page only displaying one of the charts?

Tags: html, css, chart.js

When I comment one of the charts out, the other magically appears. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here... I even made sure the containers they're in are transparent. Please note I had to cut some data out to post-ignore the weird-looking graphs Lol. Just need them both on the same page. Thank you in advance!

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.2.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
          
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class ="h">
        <canvas id="height" width="90%" height="25%"></canvas>
        <script>
            const ctx = document.getElementById('height').getContext('2d');
            const xlabels = ['607', '894', '913', '932', '951', '970', '989', '1008', '1027', '1046',  '1317', '1336', '1355', '1375', '1393', '1413', '1431', '1451', '1637', '1905', '1925', '1944', '1963', '1982', '2000', '2020', '2038', '2058', '22326', '2344', '2364', '2382', '2402', '2420', '2445', '2633', '2651', '2917', '2935', '2953', '2971', '2990', '3009', '3027', '3047', '3066', '3837', '3356', '3375', '3394', '3412', '3432', '3450', '3638', '3655', '3747', '3946', '3964', '3984', '4002', '4022', '4040', '4060', '4078', '4098', '4361', '4379', '4399', '4417', '4436', '4458', '4705', '4748', '4766',, '5032', '5056', '0528', '10553', '10572', '0', '10819', '10838', '10857', '10880', '10899', '10917', '10937', '10956', '1440', '11464', '11484', '11502', '11522', '11540', '11559', '11579', '115', '11830', '11849', '11868', '12116', '12161', '12180', '12198', '12218', '0', '12470', '12488', '12508', '12526', '12546', '12564', '12583', '12602', '3000', '13019', '13038', '13057', '13076', '13094', '13114', '13132', '131', '13385', '13404', '13423', '13442', '13461', '13479', '13504', '13521', '7', '14024', '14043', '14062', '14086', '14105', '14124', '14143', '14162', '4391', '14415', '14434', '14453', '14473', '14492', '14511', '14530', '145', '14949', '14968', '14987', '15006', '15025', '15044', '15063', '15082', '2', '15331', '15352', '15369', '15388', '15407', '15426', '15444', '15464','5864', '15883', '15902', '15921', '15940', '15959', '15978', '15996', '160', '16249', '16268', '16287', '16306', '16325', '16344', '16366', '16386', '0', '16888', '16908', '16931', '16951', '16969', '16989', '17008', '17027', '7260', '17278', '17298', '17317', '17336', '17355', '17375', '17393', '174', '17812', '17830', '17850', '17868', '17888', '17906', '17926', '17944', '4', '18196', '18212', '18232', '18250', '18270', '18289', '18308', '18327', '8727', '18746', '18765', '18784', '18803', '18822', '18841', '18860', '1881', '19659', '19679', '19703', '19722', '19741', '19760', '19779', '19798', '20029', '20047', '20067', '20086', '20105', '20124', '20143'];
            const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: xlabels,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Height(m)',
                        data: xlabels,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'

                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        </script>
        </div>

    
       
        <div class ="x">
            <canvas id="x" width="90%" height="25%"></canvas>
            <script>
                const ctx = document.getElementById('x').getContext('2d');
                const ylabels = ['0.28', '0.04', '0.03', '0.03', '0.24', '0.01', '-0.28', '-0.14', '-0.03', '0.05', '0.28', '-0.03', '0.19', '0.08', '0.04', '-0.08', '0.04', '-0.01', '-0.19', '-0.13', '-0.19', 
                                    '-0.19', '-0.00', '0.09', '0.25', '0.05', '-0.08', '-0.16', '-0.63', '-0.26', '-0.21', '0.08', '0.05', '0.03', '0.05', '0.00', '0.02', '0.04', '0.00', '0.10', '0.11', '0.10', '0.12', '0.03', '0.09', '0.01', '0.33', '0.12', '0.14', '0.20', '0.17', '0.10', '0.13', '0.11', '0.14', '0.16', '0.07', '0.03', '-0.04', '0.02', '-0.07', '-0.21', '-0.20', '-0.23', 
                                    '-0.25', '-0.40', '-0.31', '-0.13', '-0.10', '-0.11', '-0.30', '-0.22', '-0.05', '-0.12', '-0.52', '-0.29', '-0.14', '-0.19', '-0.53', '-0.20', '-0.20', '-0.21', '-0.20', '-0.15', '-0.21', '-0.16', '-0.15', '-0.22', '-0.16', '-0.13', '-0.60', '-0.25', '-0.41', '-0.47', '-0.22', '-0.26', '-0.31', '-0.27', '0.12', '-0.29', '-0.25', '-0.38', '-0.37', '-0.29', '-0.34', '-0.33', '-0.30', '-0.32', '-0.35', '-0.44', '-0.46', '-0.46', '-0.41', '-0.32', '-0.27', '-0.21', '-0.25', '-0.29', '-0.61', '-0.47', '-0.51', '-0.50', '-0.59', '-0.88', '-0.79', '-0.76', '-0.77', '-0.79', '-0.79', '-0.73', '-0.70', '-0.74', '-0.71', '-0.74', '-0.71', '-0.69', '-0.60', '-0.57', '-0.65', '-0.69', '-0.64', '-0.72', '-0.70', '-0.70', '-0.70', '-0.73', '-0.83', '-0.85', '-0.77', '-0.77', '-0.71', '-0.76', '-0.95', '-0.77', '-0.81', '-0.85', '-0.77', '-0.70', '-0.68', '-0.66', '-0.63', '-0.63', '-0.69', 
                                    '-0.37', '-0.13', '-0.08', '-0.17', '-0.35', '-0.34', '-0.30', '-0.32', '-0.38', '-0.39', '-0.37', '-0.18', '-0.26', '-0.41', '-0.28', '-0.23', '-0.33', '-0.34', '-0.10', '0.12', '0.20', '0.30', '0.06', '0.26', '0.16', '0.21', '0.10', '0.16', '-0.02', '-0.27', '0.09', '0.58', '0.12', '0.05', '0.01', '0.08', '0.15', '0.09', '0.03', '-0.02', '-0.01', '-0.00', '0.00', '-0.02', '-0.08', '-0.14', '-0.18', '-0.23', '-0.30', '-0.36', '-0.41', '-0.41', '-0.44', '-0.25', '-0.18', '-0.17', '-0.18', '-0.14', '-0.17', '-0.17', '-0.20', '-0.31', '-0.36', '-0.23', '-0.14', '-0.19', '-0.18', '-0.50', '-0.34', '-0.47', '-0.58', '-0.59', '-1.23', '-0.98', '-0.75', '-0.66', '-0.59', '-0.63', '-0.68', '-0.78', '-0.86', '-0.72', '-0.68', '-0.70', '-0.77', '-0.90', '-1.00', '-1.10', '-1.18', '-1.24', '-1.22', '-1.22', '-1.21', '-1.04', '-0.92', '-0.76', '-0.68', '-0.65', '-0.63', '-0.61', '-0.61', 
                                    '-0.65', '-0.38', '-0.22', '-0.07', '0.02', '0.07', '0.10', '0.17', '-0.09', '-0.21', '-0.51', '-0.94', '-1.62', '-1.44', '-1.53', '-1.46', '-1.47', '-1.54', '-1.63', '-1.51', '-1.38', '-1.27', '-1.34', '-1.26', '-1.18', '-0.96', '-0.76', '-0.61', '-0.48', '-0.40', '-0.27', '-0.08', '0.02', '0.09', '0.04', '-0.78', '-0.48', '-0.64', '-0.44', '-0.30', '-0.21', '-0.13', '-0.15', '-0.18', '-0.15', '-0.19', '-0.27', '-0.29', '-0.38', '-0.47', '-1.33', '-0.60', '-0.55', '-0.47', '-0.56', '-0.55', '-0.50', '-0.38', '-0.37', '-0.40', '-0.36', '-0.27', '-0.17', '-0.11', '-0.55', '-0.48', '-0.44', '-0.47', '-0.49', '-0.53', '-0.49', '-0.53', '-0.59', '-0.56', '-0.38', '-0.24', '-0.32', '-0.32', '-0.31', '-0.27', '-0.25', '-0.27', '-0.28', '-0.27', '-0.30', '-0.29', '-0.28', '-0.33', '-0.43', '-0.52', '-0.35', '-0.56', '-0.57', '-0.61', '-0.60', '-0.52', '-0.50', '-0.59', '-0.64', '-0.65', '-0.63', '-0.55', '-0.45', '-0.38', '-0.37', '-0.35', '-0.29', '-0.24', '-0.48', '-0.48', '-0.42', '-0.36', '-0.35', '-0.34', '-0.27', '-0.24', '-0.27', '-0.29', '-0.23', '-0.23', '-0.27', '-0.32', '-0.28', '-0.29', '-0.40', '-1.02', '-0.54', '-0.50', '-0.52', '-0.44', '-0.39', '-0.44', '-0.47', '-0.52', '-0.59', '-0.62', '-0.53', '-0.41', '-0.42', '-0.40', '-0.51', '-0.79', '-0.56', '-0.54', '-0.52', '-0.52', '-0.41', '-0.35', '-0.50', '-0.67', '-0.46', '-0.40', '-0.29', '-0.24', '-0.21', 
                                    '-0.23', '-0.31', '-0.32', '-0.27', '-0.26', '-0.28', '-0.30', '-0.33', '-0.38', '-0.37', '-0.39', '-0.47', '-0.57', '-0.48', '-0.40', '-0.43', '-0.39', '-0.33', '-0.27', '-0.27', '-0.32', '-0.32', '-0.34', '-0.37', '-0.44', '-0.46', '-0.38', '-0.42', '-0.04', '-0.46', '-0.34', '-0.31', '-0.41', '-0.46', '-0.48', '-0.46', '-0.13', '0.08', '0.40', '0.24', '0.37', '0.17', '0.02', '0.02', '0.27', '0.31', '0.25', '0.32', '0.31', '0.38', '0.47', '0.42', '0.29', '0.10', '-0.17', '-0.59', '-0.62', '-0.95', '-0.87', '-0.38', '-0.18', '-0.12', '-0.07', '-0.00', '-0.05', '0.01', '-0.11', '-0.01', '0.01', '0.02', '0.05', '-0.05', '-0.38', '-0.45', '-0.34', '-0.25', '-0.36', '-0.27', '-0.18', '-0.06', '0.07', '0.22', '0.24', '0.07', '0.09', '-0.09', '-0.33', '-0.54', '-0.46', '0.40', '0.80', '0.02', '-0.00', '0.05', '0.01', '0.16', '0.23', '0.09', '-0.10', '0.30', '0.37', '0.17', '0.01', '-0.05', '-0.15', '-0.67', '-1.22', '-0.80', '-0.03', '0.18', '0.34', '0.06', '0.02', '0.08', '-0.06', '-0.08', '-0.15', '-0.24', '-0.36', '-0.27', '-0.24', '-0.22', '-0.01', '0.23', '0.24', '0.06', '0.22', '0.13', '0.15', '0.23', '-0.03', '0.23', '0.09', '-0.19', '-0.15', '-0.03', '0.02', '0.12', '0.03', '-0.09', '-0.06', '-0.08', '0.07', '-0.11', '-0.10', '0.01', '0.06', '0.07', '0.09', '0.05', '0.07', '0.15', '0.16', '0.15', '0.06', '0.08', '0.10', '0.06', '-0.14', '-0.41', '-0.39', '-0.23', '-0.13', '-0.20', '-0.16', '-0.08', '0.00', '0.01', '0.03', '0.09', '0.10', '-0.16', '0.27', '-0.12', '-0.30', '-0.48', '-0.50', '-0.41', '-0.30', '-0.30', '-0.30', '-0.21', '-0.03', '0.11', '0.14', '0.19', '0.05', '0.01', '-0.03', '-0.10', '0.12', '0.08', '0.08', '0.03', '0.05', '0.01', '-0.11', '-0.16', '-0.11', '-0.02', '0.08', '0.03', '-0.84', '-0.80', '-0.91', '-0.63', '-0.67', '-0.59', '-1.40', '-2.00', '-1.32', '-0.79', '-0.61', '-0.42', '-0.28', '-0.39', '-0.39', '-0.31', '-0.27', '-0.51', '-0.48', '-0.61', '-0.61', '-0.79', '-0.63', '-0.42', '-0.49', '-0.64', '-0.76', '-0.48', '-0.53', '-0.47', '-0.46', '-0.34', '-0.19', '-0.17', '-0.36', '-0.68', '-0.53', '-0.34', '-0.06', '-0.33', '-0.20', '-0.01', '-0.76', '-0.38', '0.21', '0.33', '-0.20', '0.11', '0.04', '-0.32', '-0.38', '-0.22', '-0.14', '-0.08', '-0.04', '0.06', '0.14', '0.16', '0.17', '0.12', '0.04', '0.12', '0.07', '0.04', '0.02', '0.01', '-0.05', '0.21', '0.12', '0.15', '0.36', '0.03', '0.15', '0.19', '0.03', '0.11', '0.17', '0.07', '0.05', '0.10', '0.10', '0.08', '0.09', '0.11', '0.27', '0.34', '-0.13', '-0.35', '-0.99', '-0.60', '-0.44', '-0.37', '-0.16', '-0.26', '-0.41', '-0.27', '-0.30', '-0.05', '-0.04', '-0.18', '-0.22', '-0.22', '-0.18', '-0.04', '-0.00', '-0.06', '-0.08', '-0.09', '-0.45', '0.26', '-0.23', '-0.24', '0.15', '-0.25', '-0.45', '0.25', '-0.16', '-0.11', '0.07', '-0.12', '-0.07', '0.07', '0.33', '0.52', '0.84', '0.46', '1.19', '1.17', '0.17', '1.00', '0.09', '-0.26', '-0.50', '-0.72', '-0.26', '0.80', '2.00', '2.00', '1.04', '0.50', '1.33', '0.64', '-0.78', '0.57', '0.56', '0.79', '0.91', '0.47', '0.51', '0.45', '0.54', 
                                    '0.58', '0.61', '0.52', '0.55', '0.53', '0.45', '0.53', '0.54', '0.47', '0.55', '0.52', '0.48', '0.38', '0.41', '0.62', '1.18', '0.47', '0.72', '0.64', '0.71', '0.68', '0.64', '0.62', '0.57', '0.72', '-0.05', '0.49', '0.16', '0.71', '0.23', '0.29', '0.52', '0.54', '0.51', '0.52', '0.34', '0.27', '0.41', '0.53', '0.54', '0.61', '0.63', '0.43', '0.50', '0.50', '0.53', '0.37', '0.85', '0.90', '0.45', '0.41', '0.31', '0.27', '0.37', '0.26', '0.08', '0.87', '-0.25', '0.17', '0.13', '0.26', '0.09', '0.06', '-0.03', '-0.04', '-0.21', '-0.16', '-0.34', '-0.31', '-0.10', '-0.07', '-0.23', '-0.51', '-0.55', '-0.47', '-0.37', '-0.43', '-0.37', '-0.44', '-0.36', '-0.39', '-0.41', '-0.51', '-0.49', '-0.48', '-0.37', '-0.57', '-0.56', '-0.43', '-0.45', '-0.50', '-0.81', '-0.70', '-0.86', '-0.10', '0.23', '-0.75', '-0.56', '-0.64', '-0.62', '-0.26', '-0.50', '-0.71', '-0.71', '-0.80', '-0.72', '-0.61', '-0.56', '-0.25', '-0.33', '-0.58', '-0.37', '-0.44', '-0.46', '-0.52', '-0.64', '-0.41', '-0.46', '-0.44', '-0.46', '-0.52', '-0.39', '-0.48', '-0.55', '-0.37', '-0.54', '-0.58', '-0.30', '-0.27', '-0.52', '-0.32', '-0.32', '-0.50', '-0.57', '-0.19', '-0.24', '-0.33', '-0.41', '-0.37', '-0.33', '-0.23', '-0.34', '-0.34', '-0.31', '-0.30', '-0.18', '-0.35', '-0.28', '-0.39', '-0.34', '-0.34', '-0.54', '-0.15', '-0.41', '-0.35', '-0.27', '-0.30', '-0.35', '-0.32', '-0.30', '-0.35', '-0.37'];
                
                    const xlabels =['607', '894', '913', '932', '951', '970', '989', '1008', '1027', '1046', '1065', '1084', '1103', '1122', '1140', '1160', '1179', '1198', '1217', '1242', '1260', '1278', '1298', '1317', '1336', '1355', '1375', '1393', '1413', '1431', '1451', '1637', '1653', '1673', '1691', '1711', '1729', '1754', '1773', '1792', '1811', '1829', '1849', '1867', '1887', '1905', '1925', '1944', '1963', '1982', '2000', '2020', '2038', '2058', '2076', '2099', '2118', '2137', '2156', '2174', '2194', '2212', '2234', '2250', '2269', '2288', '2307', '2326', '2344', '2364', '2382', '2402', '2420', '2445', '2633', '2651', '2669', '2689', '2708', '2726', '2746', '2764', '2784', '2803', '2822', '2841', '2860', '2879', '2897', '2917', '2935', '2953', '2971', '2990', '3009', '3027', '3047', '3066', '3085', '3103', '3123', '3142', '3161', '3179', '3198', '3217', '3238', '3256', '3280', '3299', '3317', '3337', '3356', '3375', '3394', '3412', '3432', '3450', '3638', '3655', '3674', '3693', '3712', '3731', '3750', '3769', '3793', '3813', '3831', '3851', '3869', '3889', '3907', '3927', '3946', '3964', '3984', '4002', '4022', '4040', '4060', '4078', '4098', '4116', '4133', '4152', '4171', '4190', '4209', '4228', '4247', '4265', '4285', '4303', '4323', '4341', '4361', '4379', '4399', '4417', '4436', '4458', '4705', '4748', '4766', '4786', '4804', '4824', '4842', '4861', '4880', '4899', '4919', '4937', '4957', '4975', '4995', '5013', '5032', '5056', '5074', '5095', '5112', '5132', '5150', '5170', '5188', '5207', '5226', '5244', '5264', '5282', '5302', '5490', '5507', '5525', '5544', '5569', '5587', '5607', '5625', '5645', '5663', '5683', '5701', '5721', '5739', '5758', '5777', '5796', '5815', '5834', '5853', '5872', '5891', '5913', '5932', '5950', '5969', '5988', '6007', '6026', '6044', '6064', '6084', '6102', '6120', '6138', '6158', '6176', '6196', '6214', '6239', '6257', '6277', '6295', '6482', '6500', '6519', '6538', '6557', '6576', '6595', '6614', '6633', '6651', '6671', '6689', '6709', '6727', '6753', '6771', '6791', '6809', '6829', '6847', '6866', '6885', '6904', '6923', '6942', '6961', '6980', '7000', '7018', '7037', '7056', '7075', '7093', '7111', '7131', '7149', '7169', '7187', '7206', '7225', '7244', '7263', '7282', '7301', '7489', '7505', '7525', '7543', '7563', '7587', '7606', '7625', '7644', '7663', '7682', '7701', '7719', '7739', '7757', '7777', '7795', '7815', '7833', '7853', '7871', '7890', '7913', '7931', '7951', '7969', '7989', '8007', '8027', '8045', '8065', '8085', '8102', '8121', '8140', '8159', '8178', '8197', '8216', '8241', '8260', '8279', '8298', '8485', '8502', '8521', '8540', '8559', '8578', '8597', '8616', '8635', '8654', '8673', '8692', '8711', '8736', '8755', '8774', '8793', '8812', '8830', '8850', '8868', '8888', '8906', '8926', '8944', '8964', '8983', '9001', '9021', '9039', '9062', '9083', '9100', '9119', '9138', '9157', '9176', '9195', '9213', '9233', '9251', '9271', '9289', '9309', '9555', '9600', '9619', '9644', '9662', '9681', '9700', '9719', '9738', '9757', '9776', '9795', '9814', '9833', '9852', '9871', '9890', '9909', '9927', '9947', '9969', '9989', '10007', '10027', 
                                    '10045', '10064', '10084', '10102', '10122', '10141', '10160', '10407', '10451', '10471', '10490', '10509', '10528', '10553', '10572', '10591', '10610', '10629', '10648', '10668', '10686', '10705', '10724', '10743', '10762', '10781', '10800', '10819', '10838', '10857', '10880', '10899', '10917', '10937', '10956', '10975', '10994', '11013', '11260', '11305', '11324', '11343', '11363', '11382', '11401', '11420', '11440', '11464', '11484', '11502', '11522', '11540', '11559', '11579', '11597', '11617', '11636', '11655', '11674', '11693', '11712', '11731', '11750', '11769', '11792', '11811', '11830', '11849', '11868', '12116', '12161', '12180', '12198', '12218', '12236', '12256', '12274', '12294', '12312', '12332', '12350', '12375', '12394', '12412', '12432', '12450', '12470', '12488', '12508', '12526', '12546', '12564', '12583', '12602', '12621', '12640', '12659', '12679', '12700', '12720', '12907', '12924', '12943', '12962', '12981', '13000', '13019', '13038', '13057', '13076', '13094', '13114', '13132', '13152', '13170', '13195', '13214', '13233', '13252', '13271', '13290', '13308', '13328', '13347', '13366', '13385', '13404', '13423', '13442', '13461', '13479', '13504', '13521', '13540', '13559', '13578', '13597', '13616', '13635', '13654', '13673', '13692', '13711', '13730', '13977', '14024', '14043', '14062', '14086', '14105', '14124', '14143', '14162', '14182', '14200', '14220', '14238', '14258', '14277', '14296', '14315', '14334', '14354', '14372', '14391', '14415', '14434', '14453', '14473', '14492', '14511', '14530', '14550', '14568', '14756', '14773', '14791', '14811', '14829', '14849', '14867', '14893', '14911', '14930', '14949', '14968', '14987', '15006', '15025', '15044', '15063', '15082', '15100', '15120', '15138', '15158', '15176', '15196', '15218', '15237', '15256', '15275', '15294', '15312', '15331', '15352', '15369', '15388', '15407', '15426', '15444', '15464', '15483', '15502', '15521', '15546', '15564', '15753', '15769', '15789', '15807', '15826', '15845', '15864', '15883', '15902', '15921', '15940', '15959', '15978', '15996', '16016', '16040', '16060', '16078', '16098', '16116', '16136', '16154', '16174', '16192', '16211', '16230', '16249', '16268', '16287', '16306', '16325', '16344', '16366', '16386', '16404', '16423', '16442', '16461', '16480', '16499', '16519', '16537', '16557', '16575', '16823', '16870', '16888', '16908', '16931', '16951', '16969', '16989', '17008', '17027', '17046', '17064', '17084', '17102', '17122', '17141', '17160', '17179', '17200', '17217', '17235', '17260', '17278', 
                                    '17298', '17317', '39684', '39705', '39727', '39976', '40031', '40051', '40079', '40100', '40122', '40142', '40164', '40185', '40207', '40228', '40250', '40271', '40292', '40313', '40335', '40356', '40378', '40398', '40420', '40441', '40466', '40487', '40509', '40530', '40551', '40572', '40594', '40615', '40636', '40825', '40845', '40865', '40887', '40908', '40930', '40950', '40972', '40998', '41020', '41041', '41062', '41083', '41105', '41126', '41148', '41169', '41190', '41211', '41233', '41254', '41275', '41296', '41318', '41339', '41364', '41385', '41406', '41427', '41449', '41470', '41494', '41512', '41534', '41555', '41577', '41598', '41620', '41641', '41662', '41683', '41705', '41726', '41922', '41940', '41962', '41984', '42005', '42027', '42047', '42068', '42090', '42112', '42133', '42155', '42175', '42196', '42218', '42240', '42260', '42281', '42309', '42330', '42351', '42373', '42394', '42416', '42437', '42458', '42479', '42501', '42522', '42544', '42565', '42586', '42607', '42629', '42650', '42675', '42695', '42717', '42738', '42760', '42781', '42803', '42823', '42845', '43096', '43152', '43172', '43194', '43215', '43237', '43258', '43279', '43300', '43326', '43347', '43369', '43390', '43412', '43432', '43454', '43475', '43498', '43517', '43539', '43560', '43582', '43603', '43625', '43646', '43667', '43688', '43715', '43737', '43928', '43947', '43968', '43990', '44011', '44032', '44053', '44075', '44096', '44116', '44138', '44160', '44181', '44201', '44223', '44250', '44271', '44293', '44314', '44336', '44356', '44378', '44399', '44421', '44441', '44463', '44484', '44505', '44526', '44548', '44569', '44590', '44611', '44636', '44657', '44679', '44700', '44721', '44742', '44764', '44785', '44807', '44827', '44849', '45100', '45155', '45176', '45198', '45218', '45240', '45265', '45287', '45308', '45330', '45351', '45373', '45393', '45415', '45436', '45458', '45479', '45502', '45522', '45543', '45564', '45586', '45607', '45633', '45655', '45676', '45698', '45719', '45741', '45931', '45949', '45971', '45992', '46014', '46035', '46057', '46077', '46099', '46120', '46142', '46160', '46182', '46203', '46225', '46246', '46267', '46288', '46310', '46331', '46352', '46373', '46395', '46416', '46438', '46458', '46480', '46507', '46528', '46550', '46571', '46593', '46613', '46635', '46656', '46678', '46699', '46721', '46741', '46763', '46784', '46806', '46827', '46849', '47102', '47158', '47178', '47200', '47221', '47243', '47264', '47285', '47306', '47328', '47349', '47370', '47391', 
                                    '47413', '47434', '47455', '47476', '47503', '47523', '47545', '47566', '47588', '47609', '47630', '47651', '47673', '47694', '47716', '47737', '47759', '48008', '48063', '48084', '48106', '48132', '48152', '48174', '48195', '48217', '48237', '48259', '48280', '48301', '48322', '48344', '48365', '48386', '48408', '48429', '48449', '48471', '48496', '48518', '48539', '48561', '48582', '48604', '48625', '48646', '48836', '48856', '48876', '48898', '48919', '48941', '48962', '48983', '49004', '49032', '49052', '49074', '49095', '49117', '49137', '49159', '49180', '49202', '49223', '49244', '49265', '49287', '49308', '49330', '49351', '49372', '49396', '49418', '49439', '49461', '49482', '49506', '49524', '49546', '49567', '49589', '49610', '49631', '49652', '49674', '49695', '49717', '49737', '49759', '49951', '49973', '49994', '50016', '50036', '50058', '50079', '50101', '50122', '50144', '50164', '50186', '50207', '50229', '50249', '50271', '50298', '50319', '50340', '50362', '50383', '50405', '50425', '50447', '50468', '50490', '50511', '50532', '50553', '50575', '50596', '50617', '50638', '50663', '50684', '50706', '50727', '50749', '50769', '50791', '50812', '50834', '50855', '51106', '51165', '51185', '51207', '51228', '51250', '51271', '51293', '51317', '51339', '51360', '51382', '51402', '51424', '51445', '51467', '51488', '51512', '51530', '51552', '51573', '51595', '51616', '51638', '51659', '51686', '51707', '51729', '51750', '51940', '51959', '51980', '52001', '52023', '52044', '52065', '52086', '52108', '52129', '52151', '52171', '52193', '52219', '52241', '52262', '52284', '52305', '52326', '52347', '52369', '52390', '52412', '52432', '52454', '52475', '52497', '52517', '52539', '52560', '52582', '52609', '52628', '52648', '52670', '52691', '52713', '52734', '52756', '52777', '52798', '52819', '52841', '52862', '53111', '53170', '53191', '53212', '53237', '53258', '53279', '53301', '53322', '53344', '53365', '53387', '53407', '53429', '53450', '53472', '53492', '53516', '53535', '53557', '53578', '53605', '53626', '53648', '53669', '53690', '53711', '53733', '53754', '53945', '53963', '53985', '54006', '54028', '54049', '54071', '54091', '54113', '54139', '54161', '54182', '54204', '54225', '54246', '54267', '54289', '54310', '54332', '54353', '54374', '54395', '54417', '54438', '54459', '54480', '54505', '54526', '54548', '54569', '54590', '54614', '54633', '54654', '54676', '54696', '54718', '54739', '54761', '54782', '54803', '54824', '54846', '55044', '55062', '55084', '55105', '55127', '55148', 
                                    '55169', '55190', '55212', '55233', '55254', '55275', '55297', '55318', '55339', '55360', '55382', '55402', '55430', '55450', '55472', '55493', '55514', '55535', '55557', '55577', '55599', '55620', '55641', '55662', '55684', '55704', '55726', '55747', '55768', '55792', '55814', '55835', '55857', '55878', '55899', '55920', '55942', '55963', '56215', '56274', '56296', '56317', '56338', '56359', '56381', '56402', '56429', '56450', '56471', '56493', '56514', '56536', '56557', '56579', '56600', '56622', '56642', '56664', '56685', '56707', '56728', '56750', '56771', '56797', '56818', '56840', '56860', '57110', '57168', '57190', '57211', '57233', '57254', '57276', '57296', '57318', '57339', '57361', '57382', '57404', '57441', '57462', '57484', '57506', '57526', '57547', '57569', '57590', '57612', '57633', '57655', '57676', '57697', '57718', '57740', '57931', '57951', '57977', '57999', '58020', '58042', '58063', '58084', '58105', '58127', '58148', '58169', '58190', '58212', '58233', '58254', '58275', '58297', '58318', '58340', '58364', '58386', '58406', '58428', '58449', '58471', '58491', '58513', '58534', '58556', '58576', '58600', '58619', '58641', '58662', '58684', '58704', '58732', '58754', '58775', '58797', '58818', '58840', '59029', '59047', '59069', '59090', '59112', '59133', '59155', '59176', '59198', '59219', '59240', '59261', '59289', '59310', '59331', '59353', '59374', '59396', '59417', '59438', '59459', '59481', '59502', '59524', '59545', '59566', '59587', '59609', '59630', '59652', '59676', '59700', '59718', '59740', '59761', '59783', '59804', '59825', '59846', '59868', '59889', '59911', '59932', '59953', '60203', '60261', '60282', '60309', '60331', '60351', '60372', '60394', '60416', '60437', '60459', '60480', '60500', '60522', '60544', '60565', '60587', '60609', '60630', '60650', '60677', '60698', '60720', '60740', '60762', '60783', '60805', '60826', '60848', '61094', '61154', '61174', '61196', '61217', '61239', '61260', '61282', '61307', '61329', '61350', '61371', '61392', '61414', '61435', '61457', '61477', '61500', '61520', '61542', '61563', '61585', '61606', '61627', '61648', '61675', '61697', '61717', '61739', '61989', '62048', '62069', '62091', '62112', '62134', '62155', '62177', '62197', '62219', '62240', '62262', '62283', '62309', '62330', '62352', '62373', '62396', '62416', '62437', '62458', '62480', '62501', '62523', '62544'];
                    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: xlabels,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: 'X-Axis Acceleration (m/ms^2)',
                            data: ylabels,
                            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'

                            ],
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            y: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                
            </script>
        </div>


        <style>

            div.x {
                        position: absolute;
                        width: 99vw;
                        height: 40vh;
                        top: 0%;
                        background-color: transparent;

                    } 

            div.h {
                        position: absolute;
                        width: 99vw;
                        height: 40vh;
                        top: 50%;
                        background-color: transparent;

                    } 
        </style>
       
          

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have common variable names that are getting overridden. keep variable names different for both charts like this ctx1-ctx2, myChart1-myChart2, xlabels1-xlabels2. see code below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.2.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
          
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class ="h">
        <canvas id="height" width="90%" height="25%"></canvas>
        <script>
            const ctx1 = document.getElementById('height').getContext('2d');
            const xlabels1 = ['607', '894', '913', '932', '951', '970', '989', '1008', '1027', '1046',  '1317', '1336', '1355', '1375', '1393', '1413', '1431', '1451', '1637', '1905', '1925', '1944', '1963', '1982', '2000', '2020', '2038', '2058', '22326', '2344', '2364', '2382', '2402', '2420', '2445', '2633', '2651', '2917', '2935', '2953', '2971', '2990', '3009', '3027', '3047', '3066', '3837', '3356', '3375', '3394', '3412', '3432', '3450', '3638', '3655', '3747', '3946', '3964', '3984', '4002', '4022', '4040', '4060', '4078', '4098', '4361', '4379', '4399', '4417', '4436', '4458', '4705', '4748', '4766',, '5032', '5056', '0528', '10553', '10572', '0', '10819', '10838', '10857', '10880', '10899', '10917', '10937', '10956', '1440', '11464', '11484', '11502', '11522', '11540', '11559', '11579', '115', '11830', '11849', '11868', '12116', '12161', '12180', '12198', '12218', '0', '12470', '12488', '12508', '12526', '12546', '12564', '12583', '12602', '3000', '13019', '13038', '13057', '13076', '13094', '13114', '13132', '131', '13385', '13404', '13423', '13442', '13461', '13479', '13504', '13521', '7', '14024', '14043', '14062', '14086', '14105', '14124', '14143', '14162', '4391', '14415', '14434', '14453', '14473', '14492', '14511', '14530', '145', '14949', '14968', '14987', '15006', '15025', '15044', '15063', '15082', '2', '15331', '15352', '15369', '15388', '15407', '15426', '15444', '15464','5864', '15883', '15902', '15921', '15940', '15959', '15978', '15996', '160', '16249', '16268', '16287', '16306', '16325', '16344', '16366', '16386', '0', '16888', '16908', '16931', '16951', '16969', '16989', '17008', '17027', '7260', '17278', '17298', '17317', '17336', '17355', '17375', '17393', '174', '17812', '17830', '17850', '17868', '17888', '17906', '17926', '17944', '4', '18196', '18212', '18232', '18250', '18270', '18289', '18308', '18327', '8727', '18746', '18765', '18784', '18803', '18822', '18841', '18860', '1881', '19659', '19679', '19703', '19722', '19741', '19760', '19779', '19798', '20029', '20047', '20067', '20086', '20105', '20124', '20143'];
            const myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: xlabels1,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Height(m)',
                        data: xlabels1,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'

                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        </script>
        </div>

    
       
        <div class ="x">
            <canvas id="x" width="90%" height="25%"></canvas>
            <script>
                const ctx2 = document.getElementById('x').getContext('2d');
                const ylabels = ['0.28', '0.04', '0.03', '0.03', '0.24', '0.01', '-0.28', '-0.14', '-0.03', '0.05', '0.28', '-0.03', '0.19', '0.08', '0.04', '-0.08', '0.04', '-0.01', '-0.19', '-0.13', '-0.19', 
                                    '-0.19', '-0.00', '0.09', '0.25', '0.05', '-0.08', '-0.16', '-0.63', '-0.26', '-0.21', '0.08', '0.05', '0.03', '0.05', '0.00', '0.02', '0.04', '0.00', '0.10', '0.11', '0.10', '0.12', '0.03', '0.09', '0.01', '0.33', '0.12', '0.14', '0.20', '0.17', '0.10', '0.13', '0.11', '0.14', '0.16', '0.07', '0.03', '-0.04', '0.02', '-0.07', '-0.21', '-0.20', '-0.23', 
                                    '-0.25', '-0.40', '-0.31', '-0.13', '-0.10', '-0.11', '-0.30', '-0.22', '-0.05', '-0.12', '-0.52', '-0.29', '-0.14', '-0.19', '-0.53', '-0.20', '-0.20', '-0.21', '-0.20', '-0.15', '-0.21', '-0.16', '-0.15', '-0.22', '-0.16', '-0.13', '-0.60', '-0.25', '-0.41', '-0.47', '-0.22', '-0.26', '-0.31', '-0.27', '0.12', '-0.29', '-0.25', '-0.38', '-0.37', '-0.29', '-0.34', '-0.33', '-0.30', '-0.32', '-0.35', '-0.44', '-0.46', '-0.46', '-0.41', '-0.32', '-0.27', '-0.21', '-0.25', '-0.29', '-0.61', '-0.47', '-0.51', '-0.50', '-0.59', '-0.88', '-0.79', '-0.76', '-0.77', '-0.79', '-0.79', '-0.73', '-0.70', '-0.74', '-0.71', '-0.74', '-0.71', '-0.69', '-0.60', '-0.57', '-0.65', '-0.69', '-0.64', '-0.72', '-0.70', '-0.70', '-0.70', '-0.73', '-0.83', '-0.85', '-0.77', '-0.77', '-0.71', '-0.76', '-0.95', '-0.77', '-0.81', '-0.85', '-0.77', '-0.70', '-0.68', '-0.66', '-0.63', '-0.63', '-0.69', 
                                    '-0.37', '-0.13', '-0.08', '-0.17', '-0.35', '-0.34', '-0.30', '-0.32', '-0.38', '-0.39', '-0.37', '-0.18', '-0.26', '-0.41', '-0.28', '-0.23', '-0.33', '-0.34', '-0.10', '0.12', '0.20', '0.30', '0.06', '0.26', '0.16', '0.21', '0.10', '0.16', '-0.02', '-0.27', '0.09', '0.58', '0.12', '0.05', '0.01', '0.08', '0.15', '0.09', '0.03', '-0.02', '-0.01', '-0.00', '0.00', '-0.02', '-0.08', '-0.14', '-0.18', '-0.23', '-0.30', '-0.36', '-0.41', '-0.41', '-0.44', '-0.25', '-0.18', '-0.17', '-0.18', '-0.14', '-0.17', '-0.17', '-0.20', '-0.31', '-0.36', '-0.23', '-0.14', '-0.19', '-0.18', '-0.50', '-0.34', '-0.47', '-0.58', '-0.59', '-1.23', '-0.98', '-0.75', '-0.66', '-0.59', '-0.63', '-0.68', '-0.78', '-0.86', '-0.72', '-0.68', '-0.70', '-0.77', '-0.90', '-1.00', '-1.10', '-1.18', '-1.24', '-1.22', '-1.22', '-1.21', '-1.04', '-0.92', '-0.76', '-0.68', '-0.65', '-0.63', '-0.61', '-0.61', 
                                    '-0.65', '-0.38', '-0.22', '-0.07', '0.02', '0.07', '0.10', '0.17', '-0.09', '-0.21', '-0.51', '-0.94', '-1.62', '-1.44', '-1.53', '-1.46', '-1.47', '-1.54', '-1.63', '-1.51', '-1.38', '-1.27', '-1.34', '-1.26', '-1.18', '-0.96', '-0.76', '-0.61', '-0.48', '-0.40', '-0.27', '-0.08', '0.02', '0.09', '0.04', '-0.78', '-0.48', '-0.64', '-0.44', '-0.30', '-0.21', '-0.13', '-0.15', '-0.18', '-0.15', '-0.19', '-0.27', '-0.29', '-0.38', '-0.47', '-1.33', '-0.60', '-0.55', '-0.47', '-0.56', '-0.55', '-0.50', '-0.38', '-0.37', '-0.40', '-0.36', '-0.27', '-0.17', '-0.11', '-0.55', '-0.48', '-0.44', '-0.47', '-0.49', '-0.53', '-0.49', '-0.53', '-0.59', '-0.56', '-0.38', '-0.24', '-0.32', '-0.32', '-0.31', '-0.27', '-0.25', '-0.27', '-0.28', '-0.27', '-0.30', '-0.29', '-0.28', '-0.33', '-0.43', '-0.52', '-0.35', '-0.56', '-0.57', '-0.61', '-0.60', '-0.52', '-0.50', '-0.59', '-0.64', '-0.65', '-0.63', '-0.55', '-0.45', '-0.38', '-0.37', '-0.35', '-0.29', '-0.24', '-0.48', '-0.48', '-0.42', '-0.36', '-0.35', '-0.34', '-0.27', '-0.24', '-0.27', '-0.29', '-0.23', '-0.23', '-0.27', '-0.32', '-0.28', '-0.29', '-0.40', '-1.02', '-0.54', '-0.50', '-0.52', '-0.44', '-0.39', '-0.44', '-0.47', '-0.52', '-0.59', '-0.62', '-0.53', '-0.41', '-0.42', '-0.40', '-0.51', '-0.79', '-0.56', '-0.54', '-0.52', '-0.52', '-0.41', '-0.35', '-0.50', '-0.67', '-0.46', '-0.40', '-0.29', '-0.24', '-0.21', 
                                    '-0.23', '-0.31', '-0.32', '-0.27', '-0.26', '-0.28', '-0.30', '-0.33', '-0.38', '-0.37', '-0.39', '-0.47', '-0.57', '-0.48', '-0.40', '-0.43', '-0.39', '-0.33', '-0.27', '-0.27', '-0.32', '-0.32', '-0.34', '-0.37', '-0.44', '-0.46', '-0.38', '-0.42', '-0.04', '-0.46', '-0.34', '-0.31', '-0.41', '-0.46', '-0.48', '-0.46', '-0.13', '0.08', '0.40', '0.24', '0.37', '0.17', '0.02', '0.02', '0.27', '0.31', '0.25', '0.32', '0.31', '0.38', '0.47', '0.42', '0.29', '0.10', '-0.17', '-0.59', '-0.62', '-0.95', '-0.87', '-0.38', '-0.18', '-0.12', '-0.07', '-0.00', '-0.05', '0.01', '-0.11', '-0.01', '0.01', '0.02', '0.05', '-0.05', '-0.38', '-0.45', '-0.34', '-0.25', '-0.36', '-0.27', '-0.18', '-0.06', '0.07', '0.22', '0.24', '0.07', '0.09', '-0.09', '-0.33', '-0.54', '-0.46', '0.40', '0.80', '0.02', '-0.00', '0.05', '0.01', '0.16', '0.23', '0.09', '-0.10', '0.30', '0.37', '0.17', '0.01', '-0.05', '-0.15', '-0.67', '-1.22', '-0.80', '-0.03', '0.18', '0.34', '0.06', '0.02', '0.08', '-0.06', '-0.08', '-0.15', '-0.24', '-0.36', '-0.27', '-0.24', '-0.22', '-0.01', '0.23', '0.24', '0.06', '0.22', '0.13', '0.15', '0.23', '-0.03', '0.23', '0.09', '-0.19', '-0.15', '-0.03', '0.02', '0.12', '0.03', '-0.09', '-0.06', '-0.08', '0.07', '-0.11', '-0.10', '0.01', '0.06', '0.07', '0.09', '0.05', '0.07', '0.15', '0.16', '0.15', '0.06', '0.08', '0.10', '0.06', '-0.14', '-0.41', '-0.39', '-0.23', '-0.13', '-0.20', '-0.16', '-0.08', '0.00', '0.01', '0.03', '0.09', '0.10', '-0.16', '0.27', '-0.12', '-0.30', '-0.48', '-0.50', '-0.41', '-0.30', '-0.30', '-0.30', '-0.21', '-0.03', '0.11', '0.14', '0.19', '0.05', '0.01', '-0.03', '-0.10', '0.12', '0.08', '0.08', '0.03', '0.05', '0.01', '-0.11', '-0.16', '-0.11', '-0.02', '0.08', '0.03', '-0.84', '-0.80', '-0.91', '-0.63', '-0.67', '-0.59', '-1.40', '-2.00', '-1.32', '-0.79', '-0.61', '-0.42', '-0.28', '-0.39', '-0.39', '-0.31', '-0.27', '-0.51', '-0.48', '-0.61', '-0.61', '-0.79', '-0.63', '-0.42', '-0.49', '-0.64', '-0.76', '-0.48', '-0.53', '-0.47', '-0.46', '-0.34', '-0.19', '-0.17', '-0.36', '-0.68', '-0.53', '-0.34', '-0.06', '-0.33', '-0.20', '-0.01', '-0.76', '-0.38', '0.21', '0.33', '-0.20', '0.11', '0.04', '-0.32', '-0.38', '-0.22', '-0.14', '-0.08', '-0.04', '0.06', '0.14', '0.16', '0.17', '0.12', '0.04', '0.12', '0.07', '0.04', '0.02', '0.01', '-0.05', '0.21', '0.12', '0.15', '0.36', '0.03', '0.15', '0.19', '0.03', '0.11', '0.17', '0.07', '0.05', '0.10', '0.10', '0.08', '0.09', '0.11', '0.27', '0.34', '-0.13', '-0.35', '-0.99', '-0.60', '-0.44', '-0.37', '-0.16', '-0.26', '-0.41', '-0.27', '-0.30', '-0.05', '-0.04', '-0.18', '-0.22', '-0.22', '-0.18', '-0.04', '-0.00', '-0.06', '-0.08', '-0.09', '-0.45', '0.26', '-0.23', '-0.24', '0.15', '-0.25', '-0.45', '0.25', '-0.16', '-0.11', '0.07', '-0.12', '-0.07', '0.07', '0.33', '0.52', '0.84', '0.46', '1.19', '1.17', '0.17', '1.00', '0.09', '-0.26', '-0.50', '-0.72', '-0.26', '0.80', '2.00', '2.00', '1.04', '0.50', '1.33', '0.64', '-0.78', '0.57', '0.56', '0.79', '0.91', '0.47', '0.51', '0.45', '0.54', 
                                    '0.58', '0.61', '0.52', '0.55', '0.53', '0.45', '0.53', '0.54', '0.47', '0.55', '0.52', '0.48', '0.38', '0.41', '0.62', '1.18', '0.47', '0.72', '0.64', '0.71', '0.68', '0.64', '0.62', '0.57', '0.72', '-0.05', '0.49', '0.16', '0.71', '0.23', '0.29', '0.52', '0.54', '0.51', '0.52', '0.34', '0.27', '0.41', '0.53', '0.54', '0.61', '0.63', '0.43', '0.50', '0.50', '0.53', '0.37', '0.85', '0.90', '0.45', '0.41', '0.31', '0.27', '0.37', '0.26', '0.08', '0.87', '-0.25', '0.17', '0.13', '0.26', '0.09', '0.06', '-0.03', '-0.04', '-0.21', '-0.16', '-0.34', '-0.31', '-0.10', '-0.07', '-0.23', '-0.51', '-0.55', '-0.47', '-0.37', '-0.43', '-0.37', '-0.44', '-0.36', '-0.39', '-0.41', '-0.51', '-0.49', '-0.48', '-0.37', '-0.57', '-0.56', '-0.43', '-0.45', '-0.50', '-0.81', '-0.70', '-0.86', '-0.10', '0.23', '-0.75', '-0.56', '-0.64', '-0.62', '-0.26', '-0.50', '-0.71', '-0.71', '-0.80', '-0.72', '-0.61', '-0.56', '-0.25', '-0.33', '-0.58', '-0.37', '-0.44', '-0.46', '-0.52', '-0.64', '-0.41', '-0.46', '-0.44', '-0.46', '-0.52', '-0.39', '-0.48', '-0.55', '-0.37', '-0.54', '-0.58', '-0.30', '-0.27', '-0.52', '-0.32', '-0.32', '-0.50', '-0.57', '-0.19', '-0.24', '-0.33', '-0.41', '-0.37', '-0.33', '-0.23', '-0.34', '-0.34', '-0.31', '-0.30', '-0.18', '-0.35', '-0.28', '-0.39', '-0.34', '-0.34', '-0.54', '-0.15', '-0.41', '-0.35', '-0.27', '-0.30', '-0.35', '-0.32', '-0.30', '-0.35', '-0.37'];
                
                    const xlabels2 =['607', '894', '913', '932', '951', '970', '989', '1008', '1027', '1046', '1065', '1084', '1103', '1122', '1140', '1160', '1179', '1198', '1217', '1242', '1260', '1278', '1298', '1317', '1336', '1355', '1375', '1393', '1413', '1431', '1451', '1637', '1653', '1673', '1691', '1711', '1729', '1754', '1773', '1792', '1811', '1829', '1849', '1867', '1887', '1905', '1925', '1944', '1963', '1982', '2000', '2020', '2038', '2058', '2076', '2099', '2118', '2137', '2156', '2174', '2194', '2212', '2234', '2250', '2269', '2288', '2307', '2326', '2344', '2364', '2382', '2402', '2420', '2445', '2633', '2651', '2669', '2689', '2708', '2726', '2746', '2764', '2784', '2803', '2822', '2841', '2860', '2879', '2897', '2917', '2935', '2953', '2971', '2990', '3009', '3027', '3047', '3066', '3085', '3103', '3123', '3142', '3161', '3179', '3198', '3217', '3238', '3256', '3280', '3299', '3317', '3337', '3356', '3375', '3394', '3412', '3432', '3450', '3638', '3655', '3674', '3693', '3712', '3731', '3750', '3769', '3793', '3813', '3831', '3851', '3869', '3889', '3907', '3927', '3946', '3964', '3984', '4002', '4022', '4040', '4060', '4078', '4098', '4116', '4133', '4152', '4171', '4190', '4209', '4228', '4247', '4265', '4285', '4303', '4323', '4341', '4361', '4379', '4399', '4417', '4436', '4458', '4705', '4748', '4766', '4786', '4804', '4824', '4842', '4861', '4880', '4899', '4919', '4937', '4957', '4975', '4995', '5013', '5032', '5056', '5074', '5095', '5112', '5132', '5150', '5170', '5188', '5207', '5226', '5244', '5264', '5282', '5302', '5490', '5507', '5525', '5544', '5569', '5587', '5607', '5625', '5645', '5663', '5683', '5701', '5721', '5739', '5758', '5777', '5796', '5815', '5834', '5853', '5872', '5891', '5913', '5932', '5950', '5969', '5988', '6007', '6026', '6044', '6064', '6084', '6102', '6120', '6138', '6158', '6176', '6196', '6214', '6239', '6257', '6277', '6295', '6482', '6500', '6519', '6538', '6557', '6576', '6595', '6614', '6633', '6651', '6671', '6689', '6709', '6727', '6753', '6771', '6791', '6809', '6829', '6847', '6866', '6885', '6904', '6923', '6942', '6961', '6980', '7000', '7018', '7037', '7056', '7075', '7093', '7111', '7131', '7149', '7169', '7187', '7206', '7225', '7244', '7263', '7282', '7301', '7489', '7505', '7525', '7543', '7563', '7587', '7606', '7625', '7644', '7663', '7682', '7701', '7719', '7739', '7757', '7777', '7795', '7815', '7833', '7853', '7871', '7890', '7913', '7931', '7951', '7969', '7989', '8007', '8027', '8045', '8065', '8085', '8102', '8121', '8140', '8159', '8178', '8197', '8216', '8241', '8260', '8279', '8298', '8485', '8502', '8521', '8540', '8559', '8578', '8597', '8616', '8635', '8654', '8673', '8692', '8711', '8736', '8755', '8774', '8793', '8812', '8830', '8850', '8868', '8888', '8906', '8926', '8944', '8964', '8983', '9001', '9021', '9039', '9062', '9083', '9100', '9119', '9138', '9157', '9176', '9195', '9213', '9233', '9251', '9271', '9289', '9309', '9555', '9600', '9619', '9644', '9662', '9681', '9700', '9719', '9738', '9757', '9776', '9795', '9814', '9833', '9852', '9871', '9890', '9909', '9927', '9947', '9969', '9989', '10007', '10027', 
                                    '10045', '10064', '10084', '10102', '10122', '10141', '10160', '10407', '10451', '10471', '10490', '10509', '10528', '10553', '10572', '10591', '10610', '10629', '10648', '10668', '10686', '10705', '10724', '10743', '10762', '10781', '10800', '10819', '10838', '10857', '10880', '10899', '10917', '10937', '10956', '10975', '10994', '11013', '11260', '11305', '11324', '11343', '11363', '11382', '11401', '11420', '11440', '11464', '11484', '11502', '11522', '11540', '11559', '11579', '11597', '11617', '11636', '11655', '11674', '11693', '11712', '11731', '11750', '11769', '11792', '11811', '11830', '11849', '11868', '12116', '12161', '12180', '12198', '12218', '12236', '12256', '12274', '12294', '12312', '12332', '12350', '12375', '12394', '12412', '12432', '12450', '12470', '12488', '12508', '12526', '12546', '12564', '12583', '12602', '12621', '12640', '12659', '12679', '12700', '12720', '12907', '12924', '12943', '12962', '12981', '13000', '13019', '13038', '13057', '13076', '13094', '13114', '13132', '13152', '13170', '13195', '13214', '13233', '13252', '13271', '13290', '13308', '13328', '13347', '13366', '13385', '13404', '13423', '13442', '13461', '13479', '13504', '13521', '13540', '13559', '13578', '13597', '13616', '13635', '13654', '13673', '13692', '13711', '13730', '13977', '14024', '14043', '14062', '14086', '14105', '14124', '14143', '14162', '14182', '14200', '14220', '14238', '14258', '14277', '14296', '14315', '14334', '14354', '14372', '14391', '14415', '14434', '14453', '14473', '14492', '14511', '14530', '14550', '14568', '14756', '14773', '14791', '14811', '14829', '14849', '14867', '14893', '14911', '14930', '14949', '14968', '14987', '15006', '15025', '15044', '15063', '15082', '15100', '15120', '15138', '15158', '15176', '15196', '15218', '15237', '15256', '15275', '15294', '15312', '15331', '15352', '15369', '15388', '15407', '15426', '15444', '15464', '15483', '15502', '15521', '15546', '15564', '15753', '15769', '15789', '15807', '15826', '15845', '15864', '15883', '15902', '15921', '15940', '15959', '15978', '15996', '16016', '16040', '16060', '16078', '16098', '16116', '16136', '16154', '16174', '16192', '16211', '16230', '16249', '16268', '16287', '16306', '16325', '16344', '16366', '16386', '16404', '16423', '16442', '16461', '16480', '16499', '16519', '16537', '16557', '16575', '16823', '16870', '16888', '16908', '16931', '16951', '16969', '16989', '17008', '17027', '17046', '17064', '17084', '17102', '17122', '17141', '17160', '17179', '17200', '17217', '17235', '17260', '17278', 
                                    '17298', '17317', '39684', '39705', '39727', '39976', '40031', '40051', '40079', '40100', '40122', '40142', '40164', '40185', '40207', '40228', '40250', '40271', '40292', '40313', '40335', '40356', '40378', '40398', '40420', '40441', '40466', '40487', '40509', '40530', '40551', '40572', '40594', '40615', '40636', '40825', '40845', '40865', '40887', '40908', '40930', '40950', '40972', '40998', '41020', '41041', '41062', '41083', '41105', '41126', '41148', '41169', '41190', '41211', '41233', '41254', '41275', '41296', '41318', '41339', '41364', '41385', '41406', '41427', '41449', '41470', '41494', '41512', '41534', '41555', '41577', '41598', '41620', '41641', '41662', '41683', '41705', '41726', '41922', '41940', '41962', '41984', '42005', '42027', '42047', '42068', '42090', '42112', '42133', '42155', '42175', '42196', '42218', '42240', '42260', '42281', '42309', '42330', '42351', '42373', '42394', '42416', '42437', '42458', '42479', '42501', '42522', '42544', '42565', '42586', '42607', '42629', '42650', '42675', '42695', '42717', '42738', '42760', '42781', '42803', '42823', '42845', '43096', '43152', '43172', '43194', '43215', '43237', '43258', '43279', '43300', '43326', '43347', '43369', '43390', '43412', '43432', '43454', '43475', '43498', '43517', '43539', '43560', '43582', '43603', '43625', '43646', '43667', '43688', '43715', '43737', '43928', '43947', '43968', '43990', '44011', '44032', '44053', '44075', '44096', '44116', '44138', '44160', '44181', '44201', '44223', '44250', '44271', '44293', '44314', '44336', '44356', '44378', '44399', '44421', '44441', '44463', '44484', '44505', '44526', '44548', '44569', '44590', '44611', '44636', '44657', '44679', '44700', '44721', '44742', '44764', '44785', '44807', '44827', '44849', '45100', '45155', '45176', '45198', '45218', '45240', '45265', '45287', '45308', '45330', '45351', '45373', '45393', '45415', '45436', '45458', '45479', '45502', '45522', '45543', '45564', '45586', '45607', '45633', '45655', '45676', '45698', '45719', '45741', '45931', '45949', '45971', '45992', '46014', '46035', '46057', '46077', '46099', '46120', '46142', '46160', '46182', '46203', '46225', '46246', '46267', '46288', '46310', '46331', '46352', '46373', '46395', '46416', '46438', '46458', '46480', '46507', '46528', '46550', '46571', '46593', '46613', '46635', '46656', '46678', '46699', '46721', '46741', '46763', '46784', '46806', '46827', '46849', '47102', '47158', '47178', '47200', '47221', '47243', '47264', '47285', '47306', '47328', '47349', '47370', '47391', 
                                    '47413', '47434', '47455', '47476', '47503', '47523', '47545', '47566', '47588', '47609', '47630', '47651', '47673', '47694', '47716', '47737', '47759', '48008', '48063', '48084', '48106', '48132', '48152', '48174', '48195', '48217', '48237', '48259', '48280', '48301', '48322', '48344', '48365', '48386', '48408', '48429', '48449', '48471', '48496', '48518', '48539', '48561', '48582', '48604', '48625', '48646', '48836', '48856', '48876', '48898', '48919', '48941', '48962', '48983', '49004', '49032', '49052', '49074', '49095', '49117', '49137', '49159', '49180', '49202', '49223', '49244', '49265', '49287', '49308', '49330', '49351', '49372', '49396', '49418', '49439', '49461', '49482', '49506', '49524', '49546', '49567', '49589', '49610', '49631', '49652', '49674', '49695', '49717', '49737', '49759', '49951', '49973', '49994', '50016', '50036', '50058', '50079', '50101', '50122', '50144', '50164', '50186', '50207', '50229', '50249', '50271', '50298', '50319', '50340', '50362', '50383', '50405', '50425', '50447', '50468', '50490', '50511', '50532', '50553', '50575', '50596', '50617', '50638', '50663', '50684', '50706', '50727', '50749', '50769', '50791', '50812', '50834', '50855', '51106', '51165', '51185', '51207', '51228', '51250', '51271', '51293', '51317', '51339', '51360', '51382', '51402', '51424', '51445', '51467', '51488', '51512', '51530', '51552', '51573', '51595', '51616', '51638', '51659', '51686', '51707', '51729', '51750', '51940', '51959', '51980', '52001', '52023', '52044', '52065', '52086', '52108', '52129', '52151', '52171', '52193', '52219', '52241', '52262', '52284', '52305', '52326', '52347', '52369', '52390', '52412', '52432', '52454', '52475', '52497', '52517', '52539', '52560', '52582', '52609', '52628', '52648', '52670', '52691', '52713', '52734', '52756', '52777', '52798', '52819', '52841', '52862', '53111', '53170', '53191', '53212', '53237', '53258', '53279', '53301', '53322', '53344', '53365', '53387', '53407', '53429', '53450', '53472', '53492', '53516', '53535', '53557', '53578', '53605', '53626', '53648', '53669', '53690', '53711', '53733', '53754', '53945', '53963', '53985', '54006', '54028', '54049', '54071', '54091', '54113', '54139', '54161', '54182', '54204', '54225', '54246', '54267', '54289', '54310', '54332', '54353', '54374', '54395', '54417', '54438', '54459', '54480', '54505', '54526', '54548', '54569', '54590', '54614', '54633', '54654', '54676', '54696', '54718', '54739', '54761', '54782', '54803', '54824', '54846', '55044', '55062', '55084', '55105', '55127', '55148', 
                                    '55169', '55190', '55212', '55233', '55254', '55275', '55297', '55318', '55339', '55360', '55382', '55402', '55430', '55450', '55472', '55493', '55514', '55535', '55557', '55577', '55599', '55620', '55641', '55662', '55684', '55704', '55726', '55747', '55768', '55792', '55814', '55835', '55857', '55878', '55899', '55920', '55942', '55963', '56215', '56274', '56296', '56317', '56338', '56359', '56381', '56402', '56429', '56450', '56471', '56493', '56514', '56536', '56557', '56579', '56600', '56622', '56642', '56664', '56685', '56707', '56728', '56750', '56771', '56797', '56818', '56840', '56860', '57110', '57168', '57190', '57211', '57233', '57254', '57276', '57296', '57318', '57339', '57361', '57382', '57404', '57441', '57462', '57484', '57506', '57526', '57547', '57569', '57590', '57612', '57633', '57655', '57676', '57697', '57718', '57740', '57931', '57951', '57977', '57999', '58020', '58042', '58063', '58084', '58105', '58127', '58148', '58169', '58190', '58212', '58233', '58254', '58275', '58297', '58318', '58340', '58364', '58386', '58406', '58428', '58449', '58471', '58491', '58513', '58534', '58556', '58576', '58600', '58619', '58641', '58662', '58684', '58704', '58732', '58754', '58775', '58797', '58818', '58840', '59029', '59047', '59069', '59090', '59112', '59133', '59155', '59176', '59198', '59219', '59240', '59261', '59289', '59310', '59331', '59353', '59374', '59396', '59417', '59438', '59459', '59481', '59502', '59524', '59545', '59566', '59587', '59609', '59630', '59652', '59676', '59700', '59718', '59740', '59761', '59783', '59804', '59825', '59846', '59868', '59889', '59911', '59932', '59953', '60203', '60261', '60282', '60309', '60331', '60351', '60372', '60394', '60416', '60437', '60459', '60480', '60500', '60522', '60544', '60565', '60587', '60609', '60630', '60650', '60677', '60698', '60720', '60740', '60762', '60783', '60805', '60826', '60848', '61094', '61154', '61174', '61196', '61217', '61239', '61260', '61282', '61307', '61329', '61350', '61371', '61392', '61414', '61435', '61457', '61477', '61500', '61520', '61542', '61563', '61585', '61606', '61627', '61648', '61675', '61697', '61717', '61739', '61989', '62048', '62069', '62091', '62112', '62134', '62155', '62177', '62197', '62219', '62240', '62262', '62283', '62309', '62330', '62352', '62373', '62396', '62416', '62437', '62458', '62480', '62501', '62523', '62544'];
                    const myChart2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: xlabels2,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: 'X-Axis Acceleration (m/ms^2)',
                            data: ylabels,
                            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'

                            ],
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            y: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                
            </script>
        </div>


        <style>

            div.x {
                        position: absolute;
                        width: 99vw;
                        height: 40vh;
                        top: 0%;
                        background-color: transparent;

                    } 

            div.h {
                        position: absolute;
                        width: 99vw;
                        height: 40vh;
                        top: 50%;
                        background-color: transparent;

                    } 
        </style>
       
          

    </body>
</html>
```